# How to run/test app in Debug mode (F5) and have Output window still visible during the app run (VS Express 2015)

Tags: c#, debugging

I am new to Visual Studio Express 2015 and whole C# stuff (I come from the JAVA world).

I want to see some test string output (like checking variable values etc.) I am sending with `Debug.WriteLine()` during Debug mode run (<kbd>F5</kbd>), but the output window disappears immediately (is replaced by split dual windows). Yet when I close the running app, output window shows up back again WITH MY TEST STRING OUTPUT from `Debug.WriteLine();` there - how come?

This is what I call "output window" (sorry, don't know how to call it when it has written Output on it, really...)

[image]

This is what I see when I test/run (<kbd>F5</kbd>) my app ("output" window is gone):

[image]

And this is what I see when I stop/close my app - "output" window is back again also with my test string I sent with `Debug.WriteLine()`:

[image]

How can I run my app in Debug mode and also make that output window still visible during the run/test, so I could see my string output in realtime?

I need to see some test values I am sending to the output, or is there some other way how to do this in C#/Visual Studio Express 2015?

In JAVA I use NetBeans and I use Output window/CMD exactly for this, so I thought this is its equivalent. And as I see the output actually is there, it probably is, right?

Just to clarify even more: I am not creating console app that runs in CMD window, I just need to see that test output somewhere and I thought - being completely new to C# coming from JAVA - that the Output window is the place where I can see it.

Like when you C# guys need to see some test values in realtime during the app run/test, how do you do that - where your output goes? Or are you telling me there is nothing like this in Visual Studio GUI (I don't think so as I see after the app is closed my test value is present in that "output" window - the window is just not there during the app run, so...)?

I have the namespace `using System.Diagnostics;` in place, yet it still act as described above: in Debug mode the output window disappears, so I don't know what the string output is (have no clue how to make the window being visible still) and only comes back again once the app is closed (then there is my string output presented in the output window), with the Release mode the output window is there but no string output is displayed - it stays completely empty during the app run/test.

Comment: `Ctrl-Alt-O` opens the output window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to enable it..through the Debug->Windows->Output

[image]